# Entity framework code first cant create primary and foreign key relationship

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to create a relationship between two tables but keep getting the following error:

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'CallLogId' on type
>   'Ylp.Web.ParkingApi.DataLayer.Entities.ApiCallLogDetailEntity' is not
>   valid. The navigation property 'ApiCallLog' was not found on the
>   dependent type
>   'Ylp.Web.ParkingApi.DataLayer.Entities.ApiCallLogDetailEntity'. The
>   Name value should be a valid navigation property name.

DbContextMapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApiCallLogDetailEntity>()
    .HasRequired<ApiCallLogEntity>(p => p.ApiCallLog);
```

Primary table:

```
[Table("ApiCallLog")]
        public class ApiCallLogEntity
        {
            [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
            public string CallLogId { get; set; }

            [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
            public string UserId { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public string CallFilterId { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public int Count { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<ApiCallLogDetailEntity> Details { get; set; }
        }
```

foreign table:

```
[Table("ApiCallLogDetail")]
public class ApiCallLogDetailEntity
{
    [ForeignKey("ApiCallLog")]
    public string CallLogId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string PrametersHashCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }

    public ApiCallLogEntity ApiCallLog { get;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foreign key must refer to the whole primary key of the parent table. In your parent table you have a composite primary key which includes `CallLogId` and `UserId`. The message is confusing, but this can be part of the error. Is it really necessary to include the `UserId` in the PK?

Another error is that you have not defined the PK in the dependent table. If the `UserId` is also necessary on the PK, include it in the dependent table, and make it part of the FK.